# What is temporal object in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

I was exploring [`TemporalQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalQuery.html) and [`TemporalAccessor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html) introduced in Java 8. `TemporalAccessor` seems to be specially designed for temporal objects such as date, time, offset or some combination of these . What are temporal objects? 
Some googling gave its meaning as

> An object that changes over time

But not able to relate this in the context of Java?

Comment: Whilst not language specific, this might help you understand the concept: http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~jacques/cursos/map/recursos/fowler-ap/Analysis%20Pattern%20Temporal%20Object.htm

Comment: Temporal just means "time related". java.time Objects (like their joda time counterparts) are immutable, so do not change. Ever.

Answer (score 10):

According to with *Joda-Time & JSR 310, Problems, Concepts and Approaches* [[**PDF**]](http://file.ithome.com.tw/20130806/A1-1330%20-%201415.pdf), the `TemporalAccessor`:

> Defines **read-only** access to a temporal object,
>   such as a date, time, offset or some combination
>   of these

The [*JSR-310 Date and Time API Guide*](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html) states:

> Fields and units work together with the abstractions `Temporal` and `TemporalAccessor` provide access to date-time classes in a **generic manner**.

The book [*Beginning Java 8 Fundamentals: Language Syntax, Arrays, Data Types, Objects, and Regular Expressions*](http://www.apress.com/9781430266525) says:

> All classes in the API that specify some kind of date, time, or both are `TemporalAccesor`. `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime`, and `ZoneDateTime` are some examples of `TemporalAccesor`.

The next is a example code (based from some examples in the previous book):

> ```
> public static boolean isFriday13(TemporalAccessor ta) {
>     if (ta.isSupported(DAY_OF_MONTH) && ta.isSupported(DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
>         int dayOfMonth = ta.get(DAY_OF_MONTH);
>         int weekDay = ta.get(DAY_OF_WEEK);
>         DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.of(weekDay);
>         if (dayOfMonth == 13 && dayOfWeek == FRIDAY) {
>             return true;
>         }
>     }
>     return false;
> }
>
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
>     TemporalAccessor ta = formatter.parse("02/13/2015");
>     LocalDate ld = LocalDate.from(ta);
>     System.out.println(ld);
>     System.out.println(isFriday13(ld));
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks Paul. On a macro level, I could see that TemporalAccessor act on generic fields and units of temporal objects. I think, still more to explore for me in this regard. :)

Answer (score 2):

Temporal Objects  are basically the objects which have different related values like for example last day of the month", or "next Wednesday" etc in context of date object. In Java8 These are modeled as functions that adjust a base date-time.The functions implement **TemporalAdjuster** and operate on Temporal. For example, to find the first occurrence of a day-of-week after a given date, use **TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek)**, such as **date.with(next(MONDAY))**.

Comment: In the link shared by @Luke Peterson, temporal object is something which has versions and continuity. Here, a single date object could be viewed as a temporal since we can have many relative values. For eg., next monday, first day of next month etc. These relative values can be versions and single date object represents continuity.