# Get correct temporal type from passed object

Tags: java, localdate, java-time

Is there a way to determine the temporal type of a passed object? Currently I have a `Temporal` parameter that turns a `Temporal` into a `LocalDate` and returns the `LocalDate` object.

Assuming I pass a `LocalDateTime` in this `Temporal` parameter, the method will raise an exception.

Is there a way to find out the type of the passed temporal?

Comment: Show us your code and the exception message and what you expect to happen when passing in a ` LocalDateTime`.

Comment: I think you will find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229721/what-is-temporal-object-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know how you made your conversion to `LocalDate`. I believe that this one works.

```
/**
 * @throws DateTimeException if the <code>Temporal</code> hasn’t got
 * enough supported fields for a <code>LocalDate</code>.
 */
public static LocalDate convertToLocalDate(Temporal t) {
    return LocalDate.from(t);
}
```

It has no problem accepting a `LocalDateTime`:

```
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Qyzylorda"));
    System.out.println("As LocalDate: " + convertToLocalDate(ldt));
```

When I ran this code just now, I got this output:

> ```
> As LocalDate: 2020-03-13
> ```

It doesn’t work for just any `Temporal` at all, of course.

```
    convertToLocalDate(Year.of(2021));
```

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: 2021 of type java.time.Year
>   at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.from(LocalDate.java:396)
>   at com.ajax.Demo.convertToLocalDate(ConvertTemporalToLocalDate.java:18)
>   at com.ajax.Demo.main(ConvertTemporalToLocalDate.java:25)
> ```